# Loading images in a javascript loop doesn't get correct value of the loop

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with looping over loading images:

```
var m = ["http://localhost:801/grillduck/img/mark1.jpg", "http://localhost:801/grillduck/img/mark2.jpg"];

for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {

  var img = $("<img />").attr('src', m[i]).load(function() {

      console.log($(this).height());
      console.log($(this).width());
      console.log(i); // PROBLEM here always return 2 instead of 0 then 1

      var content = $('<div class="ho-content" id="demo-content' + i + '">');
  });       

}
```

problem is that I need to get the correct value of I for the loop in order to create div but it always return 2.

Cheerio,
Mark

Comment: use `var i` and you allways override content

Comment: The problem is explained in the dup, but in your case the simplest solution would be to use `$.each(m, function(i,img){...}` to avoid the issue altogether.

Comment: It is because you are not using `var i`

Comment: not using var is not right. I put var there and it still the same. Can anyone please point out how can I implement Javascript closure inside loops in my case. I tried it but could get it to work

Comment: I was using isotope metafizzy to sort images. after putting the <div class="hover-content-block"> into the img load function, it no longer sorting.